# Why does C++ span's C style array constructor need type_identity_t?

Tags: c++, c++20, ctad, std-span

The C style array constructor for span is specified as follows

```
template<size_t N> constexpr span(
   type_identity_t<element_type> (&arr)[N]) noexcept;
```

Why is `type_identity_t` necessary? instead of just:

```
template<size_t N> constexpr span(
   element_type (&arr)[N]) noexcept;
```

As was originally defined in [this proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r7.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

As [cbhattac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76469801/1774667)'s answer explains, the problem was that span's deduction guide's picked the wrong overload.

In [issue3369](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3369) a fix was developed.

The core problem was that:

```
template <size_t Size>
  requires (Extent == dynamic_extent || Extent == Size)
span(T (&)[Size]) {}
```

ctor generates an implicit deduction guide, and so does

```
template <typename T, size_t Extent>
span(T (&)[Extent]) -> span<T, Extent>;
```

The constructor builds a `span` with variable length, and the deduction guide builds one with a fixed length.

When passed an array of fixed length, the ideal deduced span should also be of fixed length.  But it wasn't happening.

Naively, explicit deduction guilds beat ones produced from constructors, but that isn't true -- the constructor here is **more constrained** due to the `requires (Extent == dynamic_extent || Extent == Size)` clause.  So it beats the deduction guide.

To fix this, `type_identity_t<T>` was used to block CTAD with this constructor completely.  (An alternative that would also work was to add a trivial constraint to the deduction guide).

Answer (score 0):

It was because *"span's deduction-guide for built-in arrays did not work"* without that change.
Please check [this link](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3369) for more details.

Comment: You should put the complete example _in the answer_, especially since it's a pretty interesting case.

Comment: I don't think I can explain it better than what Stephan explained in the link. Do you recommend that I delete my answer and add a comment to my question instead?

Comment: why did it not work? and why does it now work?

Comment: if you dont know how to say it in your own words you can include a quote from the article in your question.

Comment: If you add a description, please poke me so I can delete my answer which elaborates on yours.  Thanks!